# Loop through key and values in JSON

Tags: jquery

This is JSON returned

```
var errorsObject = JSON.parse('{ "fieldErrors": {"name":["You must enter your name1"],"name":["You must enter your name2"],"age":["Only people ages 13 to 19 may take this quiz"]}}');
```

Below code first loop working fine where I get the key name like name, age etc. In second loop want to get the values of the key selected from outer loop. `Issue is errors.fieldErrors[key]`. I need to loop only key with the name at first and get 2 values.

```
$.each(errors.fieldErrors, function(key, val) {
    alert("key->" + key); //Fine
    $.each(errors.fieldErrors[key], function(index, val) {
        alert("key->" + key + ", val->" + val);
    });
});
```

Comment: Your JSON is valid but the result would only have one "name" key, because the second one will overwrite the first one! The same key can only exist once in an object literal

Comment: Insteaed of `errors.fieldErrors[key]`, you can simply use `val` from 1st iterate.

Comment: And in second $.each() loop the key is called "index" and not "key"

Comment: @devnull69: He most likely does not care about that inner loop's index.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An object cannot contain the same key twice, so what you are trying to do is impossible. The first message is lost when the JSON is parsed.

However, your values are arrays - why not change the code returning the JSON to make proper use of those arrays? And assuming it's created by PHP code the fact that you can create such JSON smells like someone using string functions to create it instead of `json_encode` - another thing that should be changed...

Comment: You are right about "same key twice". I don't have that JSON but made it myself. That means I don't need inner loop. From first loop can get key and value to generate my errors.

Comment: You will still need to fix your JSON so it does not contain duplicate keys!

Comment: I added that duplicate key myself. I don't return duplicate key. That just came to my mind not sure why. I was wrong. Stupid question.